# Creating login session while using oracle forms

Tags: sql, oracle11g, interface-builder, oracleforms, oracle-apps

I'm trying to build an app using oracle builder (oracle forms) and i want to know the user name after login, is there any option like sessions in (PHP/ JEE) to know who logged in my app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get `User's Login&App Names`, you may prefer setting them in Forms' `ON-LOGON` trigger with `Dbms_Application_Info` package's methods using this code :

```
Declare
  v_db_name  varchar2(35) := 'mydb1'; 
  v_lg_name  varchar2(350):= 'some DesiRed Value'; -- such as a username credential when the current user is being logged on to the DB OR SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'IP_ADDRESS') provided static IP values are assigned per each user.
  v_app_name varchar2(350):= :SYSTEM.CURRENT_FORM;    
Begin
  Logon(:Parameter.Un,:Parameter.Pwd||'@'||v_db_name); -- Un & Pwd are defined in Parameters node of Forms
  Dbms_Application_Info.Set_Client_Info( v_lg_name );
  Dbms_Application_Info.Set_Module( v_app_name, null ); 
End;
```

Whenever you need who logged your application, may issue this sql to see the related session information (provided your current session has `select` privilege to query `gv$session` dictionary view):

```
select s.*
  from gv$session s
 where lower(s.client_info) like lower('%'||'&cli_info'||'%') 
   and s.module = 'myApp'   
 order by floor(s.last_call_et / 60), s.username, s.logon_time desc
```

Comment: thanks alot, i used global variables to solve this problem, thank for the info

Answer (score 0):

Sure; use "USER" system variable. For example:

```
message('You are connected as ' || user);
```